# Combinations with BigInteger in java

Tags: java, combinations, biginteger

I am working on an assignment where I have to implement a recursive way to calculate the combination of two numbers. For example, `5C3` would be `10`. That is, there are 10 combinations of 3 objects out of 5 total. However, I would like to implement a way to use the BigInteger class so I can calculate larger combinations, such is 2400 pick 3. For some reason, my code still returns a negative number, much like the behavior if it were to be regular integers. I've included my code below. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Combination {

public static BigInteger[][] memo = new BigInteger[3000][3000];

public static BigInteger choose(BigInteger n, BigInteger k) {

    if (n.intValue() == 0 && k.intValue() > 0) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    } else if (k.intValue() == 0 && n.intValue() >= 0) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else if (memo[n.intValue()][k.intValue()] != null) {
        return memo[n.intValue()][k.intValue()];
    } else {
        memo[n.intValue()][k.intValue()] = choose(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), k.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).add(choose(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), k));
    }
    return memo[n.intValue()][k.intValue()];

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.out.println("Usage: java Combination <N> <K>");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    int H = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int R = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    BigInteger N = BigInteger.valueOf(H);
    BigInteger K = BigInteger.valueOf(R);

    System.out.println(choose(N, K).intValue());

}
```

}

Comment: Check another way to implement the combinatorial without using many multiplications that could overflow the max value of integer/long variables: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/392/lectures/week6/

Comment: I deleted my answer. I was wrong. The negative value that you are saying, is it for 2400 and 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println(choose(N, K).intValue());
```

should be

```
 System.out.println(choose(N, K).toString());
```

Comment: +1. This should be it. I was looking at the wrong location and other way around. Integer overflow.

Comment: Wow thank you SO MUCH. You have no idea how much this helped. It's 1 AM here and I've been up pondering this question for a while. Thanks again!